# What kind of a plant is this and is it parasitic?

Tags: succulents

[image]

Can I please get any reference about what plant this is?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is my first attempt to ID a plant and I would say it is one of Haworthia species.

There is no need for worry because as this [site mentions](https://www.drought-smart-plants.com/haworthia.html):

> Occasionally, tall wiry stalks will emerge from most Haworthia
>   species, and charm with their sprays of pale pink or white and green
>   striped bloom.

[image: Haworthia bloom]

Comment: Great first ID False Identity!  Thank you!