# What is this dark green succulent?

Tags: identification, succulents

I know this is a very common one, but for the life of me I can't remember that name. What is it called?

[image]

Comment: I'm not an expert but I think it is one of Haworthia species. There was similar question recently https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/37301/what-kind-of-a-plant-is-this-and-is-it-parasitic/37302#37302. Someone here will probably be able to give specific answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like [Haworthiopsis limifolia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haworthiopsis_limifolia), formerly Haworthia limifolia (most of the hard leaves Haworthia were moved to the Haworthiopsis taxa.